# Elegant way to plot the L2 regularization path of logistic regression in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, regularization, lasso

Trying to plot the L2 regularization path of logistic regression with the following code (an example of regularization path can be found in page 65 of the ML textbook Elements of Statistical Learning [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf)). Have a feeling that I am doing it the dumb way -  think there is a simpler and more elegant way to code it - suggestions much appreciated thanks.

```
counter = 0
for c in np.arange(-10, 2, dtype=np.float):    
    lr = LogisticRegression(C = 10**c,
                            fit_intercept=True,
                            solver = 'liblinear',
                            penalty = 'l2',
                            tol = 0.0001,
                            n_jobs = -1,
                            verbose = -1,
                            random_state = 0
                           )
    model=lr.fit(X_train_z, y_train)


    coeff_list=model.coef_.ravel()
    
    if counter == 0:
        coeff_table = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(coeff_list,index=X_train.columns),columns=[10**c])
    else:
        temp_table = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(coeff_list,index=X_train.columns),columns=[10**c])
        coeff_table = coeff_table.join(temp_table,how='left')
    counter += 1

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)
coeff_table.transpose().iloc[:,:10].plot()
plt.ylabel('weight coefficient')
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sklearn has such a functionality already for regression problems, in `enet_path` and `lasso_path`.  There's an example notebook [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_coordinate_descent_path.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-lasso-coordinate-descent-path-py).

Those functions have some cython base to them, so are probably substantially faster than your version.  One other improvement that you *can* include in your implementation without adding cython is to use "warm starts": nearby alphas should have similar coefficients.  So try

```py
# This needs to be instantiated outside the loop so we don't start from scratch each time.
lr = LogisticRegression(C = 1,  # we'll override this in the loop
                        warm_start=True,
                        fit_intercept=True,
                        solver = 'liblinear',
                        penalty = 'l2',
                        tol = 0.0001,
                        n_jobs = -1,
                        verbose = -1,
                        random_state = 0
                       )
for c in np.arange(-10, 2, dtype=np.float):
    lr.set_params(C=10**c)
    model=lr.fit(X_train_z, y_train)
    ...
```

Comment: For the lasso_path functionality, is it only applicable to linear regression models? How should I customise it for logistic regression models?

Comment: Oh, sorry, lost track of needing classification. It doesn't appear there is a classifier version of `lasso_path`. (Also, I forgot you asked about L2 regularization, so `enet_path` would've been better for regression.)